# div overlapping a table

Tags: html, css

I have tried various options such as overlap and suchlike, but I can't stop a div from overlapping a table to the right.

I have created a fiddle for my code  http://jsfiddle.net/ntEzL/ to help explain my issue.

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; padding: 0.5em; background-color: #f1f0ee; overflow: hidden;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="ff_sidebox" cellspacing="5" style="width:22em;">Latvia
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
            <td class="" style="white-space: nowrap">Republic of Latvia</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- end of sidebox for Latvia -->
    <br>

    <br>
    <div class="ff_other_articles_caption" id="recent_articles_caption">Recent articles on Latvia</div>
    <div class="ff_other_articles" id="recent_articles">
        <div class="ff_other_articles_inner" id="recent_articles_inner">
            <ul class="block_list">
                <li> <a href="http://">Latvia becomes 18th Euro Member on Jan 1st</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
</div>
```

On a wider screen then there is no issue, but on a smaller resolution then I get the problem.

I would rather the content of the left box (div) to scroll to two lines if it can't fit there.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: hmm... maybe I meant overlay, sorry.  Not sure what overlap is?

Answer (score 0):

Both `float:left;` and `position:absolute;` cannot be together.In this case remove absolute positioning from the left side box:

If i guess right this is what you asked for:

### [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ntEzL/4/) **or** [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ntEzL/6/)

---

### Click to see updated fiddle:- [With code](http://jsfiddle.net/ntEzL/18/) / [fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/ntEzL/18/show/)

Comment: Thanks - but problem is if I remove the absolute then as you say the box drops down, which is not ideal, as it would leave a very large empty space.

Comment: then what do you want.Should it minimize its size on resizing?

Comment: Essentially, I would rather the content of the left box (div) to scroll to two lines if it can't fit there.

But still stay in the same area.

Comment: Ok i will post a fiddle later.Check for it later

Comment: Thanks.

The issue with this and other replies is that when the text on the left goes further than the box on the right, then it remains in the same column, rather than spreading out beneath the box on the right

Maybe this is my mistake in not defining my request properly.

Essentially the box on the right should simply float there and not disturb the layout of the rest of the page.

This box can be any depth depending upon the data in it.

Comment: If you want the box to shift to the bottom when the window width is less than the table width then i can do it with JQuery.Do you want a JQuery solution @Ian ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
for `.ff_other_articles` styles, remove `position: absolute` and add `width:33%`

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
position : absolute;
```

and add

```
width: 40%  !important;
```

in class 'ff_other_articles' and check the changes i have made in html.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LPJAa/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not use css `table` for this....??

i haved removed `<br />` for easier understanding....and removed `float`s too, as they are not needed if you use `floats`..[**here is the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ntEzL/12/)

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#main_container {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border:1px dashed #000;
}
.table_box_1 {
    display:table-cell;
    width:200px;
    border:1px dashed red;
}
.table_box_2 {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    border:1px dashed red;
}
```